# Who said "Rats, giant mutant rats?"

Tags: story-identification

This is a series of books about intergalactic trade starring a young man on his way up the ladder.  It is a comic adventure series.  He takes meds to control hair and beard growth and says, when frustrated, "Rats, giant mutant rats."

Comment: Lots of hits on Google, is there a reason you did not find what you were looking for there?

Comment: @JamesJenkins Apparently not.

Comment: I must admit I can't find any Google hits that look relevant. Maybe my Google fu is failing, or possibly the UK flavour Google is just being mean :-)

Comment: @JamesJenkins I must admit I spent a fair amount of time googling this, as well, and found none that seemed relevant.  I thought it would be an easy google, but there is apparently a link-building website that somehow has the phrase "giant mutant rats" highly ranked in google.

Comment: All I learnt from Googling for it is that Iran apparently has a problem with mutant rats and they're using snipers to solve it. Lots of hits doesn't mean lots of *relevant* hits.

Answer (score 9):

The only such quote I can find is from Poul Anderson's [The Van Rijn Method](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1439133263) - [see also this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicholas_van_Rijn):

> Rats! he brooded. Giant mutant rats! She'll have me hustled off the planet right away, tomorrow dawn, before I can use any information I might have gathered.

It's said by David Falkayn who is one of van Rijn's employees, but it's only said once in the book.

Re user14111's comment: the story is *A Sun Invisible*. It was published in [The Trouble Twisters](http://www.abebooks.co.uk/TROUBLE-TWISTERS-Anderson-Poul-Garden-City/1295321613/bd) in 1966. I assume the story must have appeared in a magazine before then, but I can't find a reference to it.

**Later:**

A quick PS - both van Rijn and David Falkayn use *antibeard enzyme* (sic) to stop their beards growing, so this has to be the correct book. Although I can find no mention in the story *A Sun Invisible*, in the story *The Man Who Counts* from the same book I found:

> Van Rijn stroked his goatee. The chins beneath it were getting bristly as his last application of antibeard enzyme wore off. "

Comment: Perhaps the OP would be interested in the [ISFDB](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/index.cgi) bibliography pages for [Poul Anderson](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?3) and his [Technic History](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?698) series.